# How do I remove a rusted on tire?

Tags: tires

I am restoring a 1969 Honda CT70. When it comes to the tires/wheels, I cannot get the tire to come loose from the wheel. I used a flathead and hammered it down to get between the tire and the wheel, but all it did was put a hole in that part of the tire.

I got a good look into the edge and all I can see is rust. Even rolling the tire, you can hear particles of rust and tire rolling around inside.

I've tried *Blaster* lubricant to get it unstuck because it has helped me get rust off of other parts, but it still has not worked for me. Anyone have any suggestions on what I could use without having to take it into the shop?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You may want to try taking it to a shop with a hydraulic tire machine.  These generate considerably more bead-breaking force than you can with your DIY tools.

Comment: Back in those days (1969), we would break the bead by putting a bumper jack on the tire's sidewall, and used the weight of the car to pop it.  The edge of the jack's base needs to be right tight against the rim.

Comment: Make sure that the rim's still sound after you get the tire off, clean the rust off and assess it closely.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the wheel from the CT70 and place it in the largest bench vise that you have access to. With the rim as close to the jaws as possible, tighten the vise until the rubber separates from the rim. Photo credit: rideapart.com

[image]